# steps to create abp modularity in project

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, modularity, abp

Hello I'm beginning to learn modularity and I need an example or main steps for how to create a module and how to link it with the project using ABP framework. I tried searching for some tutorials but I couldn't find any helpful steps

Comment: hi you can see this aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Module-System explain how to works module system, in abp is similar and you can see example how to use in this repo github.com/abpframework/abp-samples or check one basic example in https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-AspNetCore-Application

Answer (score 3):

Here is the cli command to add a new module.

### To add new module

`abp add-module ProductManagement --new --add-to-solution-file`

This will create a new module and add the module to your main solution.

### To add a existing free module from ABP

`abp add-module Volo.Blogging`

Here is the documenations link

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/CLI#add-module

Here is the my Blog post about it : https://blog.antosubash.com/posts/abp-add-new-module

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation which is very well documented.
The steps are as follow:

- They have part contains Tutorial you can begin with. However, I highly encourage you to read all the documentation to understand not only the Modularity, but also the convention they stipulated for the development progress using the framework (they called it best practice), and the built-in libraries they developed. because many things you may need to develop manually they properly developed it via the best way.
- They have a book to explain the DDD design pattern you also need to read. as the ABP IO framework is tightly attached to DDD. The book is AMAZING !
- They provide the source code which helped me so much to understand many implicit things that are difficult to find in documentation. and also you will have the chance to learn professional coding methods
- They have a blog for dispersed topics but I don't recommend it for the beginners
- They also have recommended some YouTube tutorial series
- Also startup templates that are preconfigured and reviewing them help well to see from the larger corner

**prerequisites**

- Strong knowledge of OOP (c#)
- Intermediate level in ASP .NET Core
- Overview about DDD (I recommend two videos populated by Steve Smith and Jason Taylor) , also the book they provide is very good
- Knowledge about at least one front-end techs Angular, React, Blazor ...etc

**Cons**

- Code missing definition and explanation
- QA problems topics are few